# How to integrate API in reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, api, react-hooks

I have an API as follows,

```
http:test.com/api/v1/getPriorityById/{priorityId}
```

useEndpointData ,

```
export const useEndpointData = <TPath extends PathFor<'GET'>>(
    endpoint: TPath,  params?: OperationParams<'GET', MatchPathPattern<TPath>>,
    initialValue?:
    | Serialized<OperationResult<'GET', MatchPathPattern<TPath>>>
    | (() => Serialized<OperationResult<'GET', MatchPathPattern<TPath>>>),
    ): AsyncState<Serialized<OperationResult<'GET', MatchPathPattern<TPath>>>> & {
    reload: () => void;
} => {
    deprecationWarning({ endpoint, params, initialValue });
    const { resolve, reject, reset, ...state } = useAsyncState(initialValue);
    const dispatchToastMessage = useToastMessageDispatch();
    const getData = useEndpoint('GET', endpoint);

const fetchData = useCallback(() => {
    reset();
    getData(params as any)
        .then(resolve)
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
            dispatchToastMessage({
                type: 'error',
                message: error,
            });
            reject(error);
        });
}, [reset, getData, params, resolve, dispatchToastMessage, reject]);

useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
}, [fetchData]);

  return {
    ...state,
    reload: fetchData,
  };
};
```

I integrated in UI as follows,

```
    const value = useEndpointData(`/v1/getPriorityById//${priorityId}`);
```

Here the prob is I will have priorityId as undefined sometimes, due to which the above api throwing 404 errors repeatedly when priority is undefined. Can any one please suggest me how to restrict calling the api when priorityId is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You can introduce a new parameter called "shouldSkip" or just "skip" if you prefer.

If the value is set to true, then you don't initate the request.

```
export const useEndpointData = <TPath extends PathFor<'GET'>>(
    endpoint: TPath,  params?: OperationParams<'GET', MatchPathPattern<TPath>>,
    shouldSkip = false,
    initialValue?:
    | Serialized<OperationResult<'GET', MatchPathPattern<TPath>>>
    | (() => Serialized<OperationResult<'GET', MatchPathPattern<TPath>>>),
    ): AsyncState<Serialized<OperationResult<'GET', MatchPathPattern<TPath>>>> & {
    reload: () => void;
}  => {
    deprecationWarning({ endpoint, params, initialValue });
    const { resolve, reject, reset, ...state } = useAsyncState(initialValue);
    const dispatchToastMessage = useToastMessageDispatch();
    const getData = useEndpoint('GET', endpoint);

const fetchData = useCallback(() => {
    if(shouldSkip) {
      return;
    }
    reset();
    getData(params as any)
        .then(resolve)
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
            dispatchToastMessage({
                type: 'error',
                message: error,
            });
            reject(error);
        });
}, [reset, getData, params, resolve, dispatchToastMessage, reject, shouldSkip]);

useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
}, [fetchData]);

  return {
    ...state,
    reload: fetchData,
  };
};

const value = useEndpointData(`/v1/getPriorityById//${priorityId}`, priorityId === undefined);
```